# Как проверить открылся ли балун маршрута в нужной области?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как проверить что балун конечной точки маршрута открылся в определенной области отмеченной GeoObject geometry.Circle
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не балун а метка конечно же, попутал

Comment: Вопрос не до конца понятен. Всё-таки, что хотите определять? Если просто хотите понять, попадает ли точка Б, введённая пользователем, в заданный круг, то достаточно взять её координаты и пересечь с кругом через стандартные методы API (смотреть в сторону geoQuery)